# Spring boot test failing to load

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've created a very simple Spring boot application and I'm testing it using some of the new test features that came with version 1.4.

The application runs fine, as do most of the tests, excluding one that has the new annotation.

```
@SpringBootTest
```

I keep getting a "missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean", which according to other questions I've seen is a problem with not having the following dependency "spring-boot-starter-web", but I have that in my pom.

Below is the failing test code and my pom.xml.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DataJpaTest
public class BookControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Test
    public void shouldRetrieveBook(){
        bookRepository.save(new Book("Java"));

        final ResponseEntity<Book> result = restTemplate.getForEntity("/books/{bookName}", Book.class, "Java");

        assertThat(result.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.OK));
        assertThat(result.getBody().getName(), equalTo("Java"));
    }
}
```

And below is the pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.scottlogic</groupId>
<artifactId>library</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>library</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Remove `@DataJpaTest`... `@DataJpaTest` (and others) and `@SpringBootTest` are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, removing @DataJpaTest did the trick.